# Check for template in a NopCommerce theme

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, nopcommerce, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to get a breadcrumb navigation to show up just below my main navigation in a NopCommerce theme, so the code to show it needs to be in Views/Shared/header.cshtml, but having it there causes pages that aren't  categories to break. Is there any way to do "if is category page, execute code" in nopcommerce? I can't find any good source of documentation for this platform...

Here's my breadcrumb code if it matters:

```
@if (Model.DisplayCategoryBreadcrumb) {
    <nav class="plain">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("HomePage")">@T("Categories.Breadcrumb.Top")</a></li>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CategoryBreadcrumb.Count; i++)
            {
                var catBr = Model.CategoryBreadcrumb[i];
                <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { categoryId = catBr.Id, SeName = catBr.SeName })">@catBr.Name</a></li>
            }
        </ul>
    </nav>
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find any good source of documentation for this platform...

nopCommerce runs on MVC, so anything that works in MVC works for nopCommerce too.

Which brings is to MVC basics. You can try go get info about current request (such as current Controller) by using the ViewContext or RequestContext whichever is relevant. For example, you can try to get the current controller by using:

```
@{
    var controller = ViewContext.Controller;
}
```

:)